# Change Submit targeted form with jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a list for product types. Each line has its own update and delete button. While each form has its only submit for update. For delete it calls another popup `div` that is created once and should target the form that owns the delete button I clicked. How do I accomplish this?

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tipoproducto";
$result = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
    <form id="tipoprod<? echo $data['id_tipoproducto']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="idprod" value="<? echo $data['id_tipoproducto']; ?>" required>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="tprod" value="<? echo $data['tipo_producto']; ?>" required></td>
    <td width="50%"><input name="act" type="submit" class="button" value="Actualizar" form="tipoprod<? echo $data['id_tipoproducto']; ?>"/>
    </form>
    <button name="del" class="button inset">Borrar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>

<div name="hoverdel" id="hover"></div>
<div name="popupdel" id="popup" class="normal">
<p><i class="icon-warning-sign icon-large"></i> Esta seguro que desea borrar este producto?</p>
<br>
<input name="borrar" type="submit" class="button inset" value="Si" form="This is what jQuery should update"/>
<button name="cancelar" class="button inset">No</button>
</div>

$("button[name = 'del']").click(function()
    {
        $("div[name = 'hoverdel']").fadeIn();
        $("div[name = 'popupdel']").fadeIn();
        $("button[name = 'borrar']").attr("form", Form Name);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess nobody got me, just added an id element to the button that gets the same value from the form and added this to the click event

```
$("input[name = 'borrar']").attr("form", $(this).attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the form before the `del` button with:

```
$(this).prev().attr('id');
```

Comment: Tried an alert with this and nothing is returned

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` around `<tr>`, `<tr>` has to be a child of `<table>` or `<tbody>`.